# Electrum transaction still says unconfirmed parent

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, electrum

A transaction from Electrum is still showing `unconfirmed parent` even though the previous transaction in the chain has completed. Electrum has shown this for 24 hours now. I realize that my fee is quite small but should it still say unconfirmed parent after so long?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: @sr_gi: The asker states that the previous transaction is completed, but Electrum still thinks it isn't. It seems to me that it's not a duplicate of the linked question.

Megarano: I assume that there is _only one_ previous transaction? There could be more than one if you're spending more than one input. If you'd be willing to share the transaction id, we could get a better understanding.

Comment: My bad, if he shares the ID I'll try to help.